# How to export a PNG with photoshop extendscript?

Tags: javascript, export, adobe, photoshop, extendscript

I just started learning photoshop scripting with extendscript, and am utterly unable to figure out how to get it to save a file, I looked in a few places on the internet, including here, adobe community forums, scripting ref ebooks, chatgpt, and saw a lot of suggestions from people and robots who seem to have gotten it working, but none of them is working for me.

Here is a list of methods I tried, which are all giving me the same error.
I only included the line of code which threw the error, which is usually the very first line that deals with defining a File object, I can't even get past that part.

`var expFile = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();`

Uncaught ReferenceError: PhotoshopSaveOptions is not defined

`var pngFile = new File("D:/temp/test.png");`

Uncaught ReferenceError: File is not defined

`var pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();`

Uncaught ReferenceError: PNGSaveOptions is not defined

`var saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();`

Uncaught ReferenceError: JPEGSaveOptions is not defined

`var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(); options.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;`

Uncaught ReferenceError: ExportOptionsSaveForWeb is not defined

`var options = new ExportOptions(); options.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG; options.transparency = true;`

Uncaught ReferenceError: ExportOptions is not defined

I'll keep looking and experimenting, but if you have a solution for me, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

It's straightforward - but only once you know:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
// otherwise you'll get asked for the file location
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF 

var afilePath = "D:/temp/test.png";

// create a file object 
var pngFile = new File(afilePath);

// create a new variable to hold the options
pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();

// I normally use these options:
pngSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
pngSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
pngSaveOptions.quality = 1; // max quality

// ... and then save out the file with the options
activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I realized after posting my question that the problem was I was trying to run the script from UXP tool by hitting the Load or Reload action from the UI. I tried the same thing by drag-and-dropping the .jsx file into photoshop window and it ran the export without issue. I suppose what I'm really trying to find out is, if there is a way to do PNGSaveOptions or exportOptionsSaveForWeb using the UXP tool UI, instead of the script file drag and drop.

Comment: You might get an answer to that from the [Photoshop forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/ct-p/ct-photoshop)